# since May it has only rained once

Tags: time-words

In the sentence "since May it has only rained once," when did the rain occur?
Did it only occur after May (e.g. in June)? Or did it occur anywhere in the period between May 1st and now?

Comment: There is no strictly correct or incorrect answer here. The phrase can mean either, and historically has been applied to both situations. In real life situations where the ambiguity is problematic, the usually course of action is to request clarification from whoever made the statement.

Comment: *Since May* would probably be understood to mean "Since the beginning of May", as any other interpretation of the time phrase presents a rather meaningless starting point. A competent speaker would not say *Since May* if the intended meaning was *Since the beginning of June*.